# store html(result) in variable and check if it equals a certain string with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code:

```
var response =  $("div.callbacktwo").html(result);

if (response == 'Added!'){
//some code here
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. I want to check if "Added!" is in the callback. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code example, the variable `response` is the jQuery object `$("div.callbacktwo")` so `response` != 'Added!'`.

Also, you ask about "in the callback", but there are no callbacks in the code you included.  Perhaps you mean to check:

```
$("div.callbacktwo").html(result);
if (result == 'Added!') {
    // some code here
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Give us a bigger context here and more of your code.  You question is not very clear and your code is certainly wrong, but without more info we're only guessing at what you're trying to do.

Comment: ahhh actually nvm. there was an issue with the php side (it was returning an extra space :p). Works now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do

```
if (result.indexOf('Added!') !== -1) {
    // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way jquery is set up to allow you chain multiple calls, your response var is actually being set equal to the `callbacktwo` element rather than `result`. I'm assuming you want to check the result, right? try this:

```
var response = reasult;
$('div.callbacktwo').html(result);

if(response == 'Added!') {
    //code here
}
```